# Lock/unlock HTML5 canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

Is there any possibility of locking `canvas` element? In my app I draw complex images and sometimes I use bitmaps. Using bitmaps with canvas isn't quite comfortable - all the drawing that should be placed on canvas after bitmap is placed in bitmaps `.onload`.

It would be a lot easier if I could lock and unlock `canvas` so it couldn't be updated for some time.

AFAIK there is no built-in function for lock/unlock. Do you know any simple way of implementing it?

Comment: I've never used canvas, but as a wild idea: You could draw on a hidden  canvas and copy the image to the visible one when you are finished.

Comment: I'm already using this technique, it's quite common :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know whether this is bulletproof or not, but you could temporarily make `.stroke` etc. noops: http://jsfiddle.net/eGjak/247/.

```
var toLock = "stroke fill".split(" ");

function lock() {
    $.each(toLock, function(i, name) { // or another way to loop the array
        ctx[name] = function() {};
    });
}

function unlock() {
    $.each(toLock, function(i, name) {
        ctx[name] = ctx.constructor.prototype[name];
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("canvas").attr("disable","False");

// bitmap .onload...

$("canvas").attr("disable","True");
```

Or

```
bitmap.onload = function(){
    var canvas = window.getCanvas();
});
```