# Temporarily lock drawing in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas, drawing

Whenever the browser is resized, I must call **javascript / jquery** to correctly resize some controls.

I went my way to optimize it the best I could, but I also wonder if I can temporarily freeze drawing until I'm done, ie.

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    Canvas.Lock;
    try
       // Do my stuff...
    finally
            Canvas.unlock;
    end;
});
```

Is this possible?

PS. What I want is to temporarily freeze the UI (disable repainting), not show some "please wait..." modal dialog while my js code is busy

Comment: Refer this:- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9209141/lock-unlock-html5-canvas

Comment: You might be interested in this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5489946/jquery-how-to-wait-for-the-end-or-resize-event-and-only-than-perform-action